# List of Core Javascript topics from novice to ninja topics to build plugins and games

Tags: javascript

Even though I know that this question has been asked many times I am not satisfied with the answers that I googled and searched.

I want to build my carrier in web development I am good at HTML and CSS. Now I want to master Javascript so that I can come up with some Plugins,Games. So which all the topics I need to master from the scratch to the advanced level in Javascript.

I am not getting where exactly to start and which all the foot steps I need to follow to achieve my goal.

As I know in this site there are many Javascript masters I want you guys to help me out.

Comment: Have you had any experience with any other programming language?

Comment: It's simple. You start somewhere and you work your way through. It's a long way to go, but *cookbooks* have never made anyone a cook.

Comment: @jeff Ya I am having experience in PHP

Comment: Anything from AJAX calls to webworkers is useful.  For games you'll want to look into canvas, there's a lot of very useful stuff the canvas can do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I would start by visiting https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript. This course covers all the main javascript elements including some oop.